# Doctrine: how do I return data from a query with a table join?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables, `votes` and `voters`.  The tables join like this: `voters.id = votes.voter_id`

The `votes` table contains the IP address at the time of the vote.

I want to select all records in the `voters` table and the IP address, by the IP address in the `votes` table.  How do I do this?  Should the method be stored in the `Votes` or `Voter` repository?

I get an error saying:  `Attempted to load class "Join" from namespace "App\Repository\Expr". Did you forget a "use" statement for "Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join"?`

I've included the line `use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;` but it doesn't get used.

For the commented out `leftjoin` I get this error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 52 near 'voters WHERE': Error: Class App\Entity\Votes has no association named voters
```

For the leftjoin I get this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 66: Error: Expected end of string, got 'ON'
```

I have this so far but its not quite right:

```
public function findByIP($value)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
        ->andWhere('votes.ipaddress = :ipaddress')
        ->setParameter('ipaddress', $value)
        //->leftJoin('v.voters', 'voters')
        ->leftJoin('App\Entity\Voter', 'voter', Join::ON, 'voter.id = v.voter_id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
```

Voter Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\VoterRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=VoterRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="voters")
 */
class Voter
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $address_line_2;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $town;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
     */
    private $postcode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     */
    private $nec_number;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateofbirth;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $first_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $last_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Votes::class, mappedBy="voter")
     */
    private $votes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->votes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress(?string $address): self
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddressLine2(): ?string
    {
        return $this->address_line_2;
    }

    public function setAddressLine2(?string $address_line_2): self
    {
        $this->address_line_2 = $address_line_2;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTown(): ?string
    {
        return $this->town;
    }

    public function setTown(?string $town): self
    {
        $this->town = $town;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(?string $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostcode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->postcode;
    }

    public function setPostcode(?string $postcode): self
    {
        $this->postcode = $postcode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNecNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nec_number;
    }

    public function setNecNumber(string $nec_number): self
    {
        $this->nec_number = $nec_number;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateofbirth(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateofbirth;
    }

    public function setDateofbirth(?\DateTimeInterface $dateofbirth): self
    {
        $this->dateofbirth = $dateofbirth;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $first_name): self
    {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->last_name;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $last_name): self
    {
        $this->last_name = $last_name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Votes[]
     */
    public function getVotes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->votes;
    }

    public function addVote(Votes $vote): self
    {
        if (!$this->votes->contains($vote)) {
            $this->votes[] = $vote;
            $vote->setVoter($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeVote(Votes $vote): self
    {
        if ($this->votes->removeElement($vote)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($vote->getVoter() === $this) {
                $vote->setVoter(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Votes Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\VotesRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=VotesRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="votes")
 */
class Votes
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $vote;

        /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $ipaddress;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     */
    private $nec_number;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Voter::class, inversedBy="votes")
     */
    private $voter;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getVote(): ?int
    {
        return $this->vote;
    }

    public function setVote(?int $vote): self
    {
        $this->vote = $vote;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIpaddress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->ipaddress;
    }

    public function setIpaddress(?string $ipaddress): self
    {
        $this->ipaddress = $ipaddress;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNecNumber(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nec_number;
    }

    public function setNecNumber(string $nec_number): self
    {
        $this->nec_number = $nec_number;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVoter(): ?Voter
    {
        return $this->voter;
    }

    public function setVoter(?Voter $voter): self
    {
        $this->voter = $voter;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr;` if later on you use `Expr\Join`. You can also `use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join;` and then use directly `Join`

Comment: Since you're using `Expr\Join` you would add `use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr;` as suggested by alexcm, below the `namespace` declaration and before the `class` declaration. It also looks like you have multiple typos in your query builder. You call `votes` but declare `v` as the alias. if the association is setup, `v.id` would be `v.voters`, as `v.id` would be an ID (integer/UUID, etc)? At which point the `JOIN:ON`  clause is not needed EG: `leftJoin('v.voters', 'voters')` If there is no association it should be `leftJoin('App\Entity\Voter', 'voter', Join::WITH, 'voter.id = v.voter_id')`

Comment: It's important to note, when using the ORM querybuilder, that you are working with the entity properties and not table column names, so normally it would be `voters.id = v.voterId` instead of `v.voter_id`. As well to retrieve the records you would also need to add `->addSelect('voters')` - provided the join alias is specified as `voters`. eg: `leftJoin([Entity-Reference], 'voters' /*, ... */)`

Comment: @WillB.Thank you for your replies, that is making sense.  I've updated my post as I tried both your suggestions.  The association doesn't appear to be set up but I did set up a relationship when I created the two entities.  Would it be worth me posting the entity files too?

Comment: Yes, posting the entities would help to verify the association/relationship and property names.

Comment: @WillB. Hi, I've posted those two entities.

Comment: Since the `ManyToOne` association between `Votes::$voter` is established your query in the `VotesRepository::findByIp()` method should look like:  `$this->createQueryBuilder('votes')->andWhere('votes.ipaddress = :ipaddress')->setParameter('ipaddress', $value)->leftJoin('votes.voter', 'voter')->addSelect('voter')->getQuery()->getResult();` Which will give you an array of `Votes` entities with the matching IP and their associated `Votes::$voter` entity.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

In `VotesRepository.php` add this method:

```
public function findByIP($value)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('v')
        ->innerJoin('v.voter','voter')
        ->addSelect('voter') //eager loading
        ->andWhere('v.ipaddress = :ipaddress')
        ->setParameter('ipaddress', $value)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute()
        ;
}
```

In the twig template add this:

```
<ul>
    {% for vote in votes %}
        <li>{{ vote.getIpaddress() }}</li>
        <li>{{ vote.getVoter().getEmail() }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I believe you should replace `->execute()` with `->getResult()` or [similar desired result-set](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/query-builder.html#executing-a-query)

Comment: @WillB. That's great thank you, I'll check that out.